# Accumulate vs fold vs reduce vs compress

Tags: functional-programming, fold

Are the functions `accumulate`, `fold`, `reduce`, and `compress` synonyms?

Comment: as function names are just that, and not all this names exists in every functional-language you should be a bit more specific on context of which functional language you use.

Comment: Is a sort of a cross-link acceptable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists Haskell is quite refined in its handling of these constructions.

Comment: `accumulate` and `reduce` are difference things in Python. The first one returns the list of all intermidiate accumulated values.

Comment: in C++, replacing std::accumulate with std::reduce can allow parallelization and vectorization, but leads to horrible bugs if your operation is not commutative and associative (axioms which the compiler can't check).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it depends on the language. It is a common function with different names in different languages.
See: [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))

But yes, it's commonly known as the names you mentioned plus `inject`.
The Wikipedia entry has a more comprehensive list of its aliases in several languages.

Comment: and also some of these names are used for slighlty different (or even completely different) meanings. Like compress to call some compression algorithm.