# Difference between fold and reduce?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, reduce, fold

Trying to learn F# but got confused when trying to distinguish between [fold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx) and [reduce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370239.aspx). Fold seems to do the [same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682371/accumulate-vs-fold-vs-reduce-vs-compress) but takes an extra parameter. Is there a legitimate reason for these two functions to exist or they are there to accommodate people with different backgrounds? (E.g.: String and string in C#)

Here is code snippet copied from sample:

```
let sumAList list =
    List.reduce (fun acc elem -> acc + elem) list

let sumAFoldingList list =
    List.fold (fun acc elem -> acc + elem) 0 list

printfn "Are these two the same? %A " 
             (sumAList [2; 4; 10] = sumAFoldingList [2; 4; 10])
```

Comment: You can write reduce and fold in terms of each other, e.g. `fold f a l` can be written as `reduce f a::l`.

Comment: @Neil - Implementing `fold` in terms of `reduce` is more complicated than that - the type of accumulator of `fold` does not have to be the same as the type of things in the list!

Comment: @TomasPetricek My mistake, I originally intended to write it the other way around.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

`Fold` takes an explicit initial value for the accumulator while `reduce` uses the first element of the input list as the initial accumulator value.

This means the accumulator and therefore result type must match the list element type, whereas they can differ in `fold` as the accumulator is provided separately. This is reflected in the types:

```
List.fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'State
List.reduce : ('T -> 'T -> 'T) -> 'T list -> 'T
```

In addition `reduce` throws an exception on an empty input list.

Comment: So basically instead of doing `fold`, you can simply add that initial value to the start of the list and do `reduce`? What's the point of `fold` then?

Comment: @Pacerier - The accumulator function for fold has a different type: `'state -> 'a -> 'state` for fold vs `'a -> 'a -> 'a` for reduce, so reduce constrains the result type to be the same as the element type. See [Tomas Petricek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9055928/152602) below.

Answer (score 189):

In addition to what Lee said, you can define `reduce` in terms of `fold`, but not (easily) the other way round:

```
let reduce f list = 
  match list with
  | head::tail -> List.fold f head tail
  | [] -> failwith "The list was empty!"
```

The fact that `fold` takes an explicit initial value for the accumulator also means that the result of the `fold` function can have a different type than the type of values in the list. For example, you can use accumulator of type `string` to concatenate all numbers in a list into a textual representation:

```
[1 .. 10] |> List.fold (fun str n -> str + "," + (string n)) ""
```

When using `reduce`, the type of accumulator is the same as the type of values in the list - this means that if you have a list of numbers, the result will have to be a number. To implement the previous sample, you'd have to convert the numbers to `string` first and then accumulate:

```
[1 .. 10] |> List.map string
          |> List.reduce (fun s1 s2 -> s1 + "," + s2)
```

Comment: Why define reduce such that it can error at runtime?

Comment: +1 for the note on the generality of `fold' & its ability to express `reduce'.  Some languages have a concept of structural chirality (Haskell I'm looking at you) you can fold left or right visually depicted in this wiki(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function). With an identity construct, the other two 'fundamental' FP operators (filter and fmap) are also implementable with an existing `fold' first-class language construct (they're all isomorphic constructs). (http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf) See: HoTT, Princeton (This comment section is too small to contain..)

Comment: Out of curiosity.. would this make reduce's performance faster than fold because it's under less assumptions about types and exceptions?

Answer (score 23):

`fold` is a much more valuable function than `reduce`. You can define many different functions in terms of `fold`.

`reduce` is just a subset of `fold`.

Definition of fold:

```
let rec fold f v xs =
    match xs with 
    | [] -> v
    | (x::xs) -> f (x) (fold f v xs )
```

Examples of functions defined in terms of fold:

```
let sum xs = fold (fun x y -> x + y) 0 xs

let product xs = fold (fun x y -> x * y) 1 xs

let length xs = fold (fun _ y -> 1 + y) 0 xs

let all p xs = fold (fun x y -> (p x) && y) true xs

let reverse xs = fold (fun x y -> y @ [x]) [] xs

let map f xs = fold (fun x y -> f x :: y) [] xs

let append xs ys = fold (fun x y -> x :: y) [] [xs;ys]

let any p xs = fold (fun x y -> (p x) || y) false xs 

let filter p xs = 
    let func x y =
        match (p x) with
        | true -> x::y
        | _ -> y
    fold func [] xs
```

Comment: You define your `fold` differently from `List.fold` as the type of `List.fold` is `('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`, but in your case `('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b`. Just to make it explicit. Also, your implementation of append is wrong. It would work if you add a bind to it, e.g. `List.collect id (fold (fun x y -> x :: y) [] [xs;ys])`, or replace cons with the append operator. Thus append is not the best example in this list.

Answer (score 19):

Let's look at their signatures:

```
> List.reduce;;
val it : (('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'a list -> 'a) = <fun:clo@1>
> List.fold;;
val it : (('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a) = <fun:clo@2-1>
```

There are some important differences:

- While `reduce` works on one type of elements only, the accumulator and list elements in `fold` could be in different types.
- With `reduce`, you apply a function `f` to every list element starting from the first one:

  `f (... (f i0 i1) i2 ...) iN`.

  With `fold`, you apply `f` starting from the accumulator `s`:

  `f (... (f s i0) i1 ...) iN`.

Therefore, `reduce` results in an `ArgumentException` on empty list. Moreover, `fold` is more generic than `reduce`; you can use `fold` to implement `reduce` easily.

In some cases, using `reduce` is more succinct:

```
// Return the last element in the list
let last xs = List.reduce (fun _ x -> x) xs
```

or more convenient if there's not any reasonable accumulator:

```
// Intersect a list of sets altogether
let intersectMany xss = List.reduce (fun acc xs -> Set.intersect acc xs) xss
```

In general, `fold` is more powerful with an accumulator of an arbitrary type:

```
// Reverse a list using an empty list as the accumulator
let rev xs = List.fold (fun acc x -> x::acc) [] xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, which already has a lot of good answers, so a bit of a different take. I have not dabbled in F# in quite a while and landed here out of curiosity for the difference between fold, reduce, collect, inject et al. A bit of research took me to the [wikipedia page on fold as implemented in various languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#In_various_languages) and from there to a very interesting paper by [Hutton Graham: A tutorial on the universality and
expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Egmh/fold.pdf) which may shed some additional light on this. Quote:

*"The fold operator has its origins in recursion theory (Kleene, 1952), while the use
of fold as a central concept in a programming language dates back to the reduction
operator of APL (Iverson, 1962), and later to the insertion operator of FP (Backus,
1978)."*

So, as far as history goes per the above quote, the terms have been pretty closely used since their origins, but fold is the one that is at the root of the others. The paper is worth a read as the author defines all the other related operations, using fold and provides a language agnostic perspective.