# F# - Same Function With Different Parameters

Tags: function, parameters, f#, option-type

In F#, is it possible for a function to take one required parameter and one or more optional parametes depending on context? In the following toy example, **whisk** initially takes *eggYolks* as its only parameter but, in the very next step, it takes the output of the initial step plus *granulatedSugar* and *marsalaWine*. Is this possible and how do I feed the additional ingredients to **tiramisu** and print out both steps to the console?

```
module Tiramisu = 

// http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/WhatsFunctionalProgrammingAllAbout.html

open System

// Ingredients.    
let eggYolks = "70<g> of egg yolks."
let granulatedSugar = "100<g> of granulated sugar."
let marsalaWine = "120<ml> of sweet marsala wine."

let whisk ingredient = printf "Whisk %s\t" ingredient

let tiramisu ingredients =
    ingredients
    |> whisk // eggYolks only.
    // |> whisk // plus granulatedSugar and marsalaWine.

[<EntryPoint>]
tiramisu eggYolks
// tiramisu (eggYolks granulatedSugar marsalaWine)
```

Comment: Not sure if your real life application is close to your sample but I think that in your sample you could get away by using sequence, array or list of ingredients.

Comment: However if you would really require a true optional parameter you would need to use Options as shown in the msdn sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters

Comment: Alexander, thanks for your comments. Can you use the toy problem (tiramisu) to illustrate your points with source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:** You should write `whisk` to take a list. See below for the full explanation, which starts with the wrong approach, explains why it's the wrong approach, and then moves to the right approach.

**Long explanation:**
The question you're asking is whether you could write the function `whisk` to take multiple things to be whisked, e.g. you're asking whether a `whisk` function could look like:

```
let whisk item1 maybeItem2 maybeItem3 =
    printfn "Whisking %A" item1
    match maybeItem2 with
    | None -> ()
    | Some item -> printfn "Also whisking %A" item
    match maybeItem3 with
    | None -> ()
    | Some item -> printfn "Also whisking %A" item
```

But this design has some problems. For one thing, this function's type signature is inconvenient: the first parameter is an ingredient, but the second and third parameters *might* be ingredients (they're actually `Option`s). In other words, if you had specified the types of the parameters in your function, they would have looked like:

```
type Ingredient = string  // For this example
let whisk (item1 : Ingredient) (maybeItem2 : Ingredient option) (maybeItem3 : Ingredient option) =
    // ... function body goes here ...
```

Why is this inconvenient? Well, if you only wanted to whisk a single thing, you'd have to call this function as `whisk eggYolks None None`. (Calling it without the two `None` parameters would get you a [partially-applied function](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/), which is a different topic). And another inconvenience: this is limited to just three items; if you wanted to whisk four items, you'd have to change the function signature, and then you'd have to change everywhere it was called to pass four parameters by adding an extra `None` to each call.

Also, this example function doesn't actually return anything, for simplicity. If it *did* return something, it gets even more complicated. For example, if you're coming from an imperative language like C#, you might try writing this:

```
type Ingredient = string  // For this example
let whisk (item1 : Ingredient) (maybeItem2 : Ingredient option) (maybeItem3 : Ingredient option) =
    printfn "Whisking %A" item1
    let mutable mixtureSoFar = item1
    match maybeItem2 with
    | None -> ()
    | Some item ->
        printfn "Also whisking %A" item
        mixtureSoFar <- mixtureSoFar + item
    match maybeItem3 with
    | None -> ()
    | Some item ->
        printfn "Also whisking %A" item
        mixtureSoFar <- mixtureSoFar + item
    mixtureSoFar
```

But that's ugly. When your F# code starts looking ugly, that's usually a sign that your design is off, somehow. For example, maybe you could let the `whisk` function take a *list of ingredients*, instead of trying to pass multiple parameters where some of them might be `None`. E.g., the `whisk` function would instead look like:

```
let whisk (items : Ingredient list) =
    // ... function body goes here ...
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
let whiskedEggYolks = whisk [eggYolks]
let mixture = whisk [whiskedEggYolks; granulatedSugar; marsalaWine]
```

What would that function look like inside? Well, it would probably apply some transformation to each ingredient, then some combining function to combine all those ingredients together into a single result. In F#, "apply some transformation to each item" is called `map`, and "apply some combining function to combine multiple items into a single one" is either `fold` or `reduce`. (I'll explain the difference between `fold` and `reduce` below). Here, I think you'd want `reduce`, since whisking an empty bowl doesn't make sense. So our `whisk` function becomes:

```
let whisk (ingredients : Ingredient list) =
    ingredients
    |> List.map (fun x -> sprintf "%s, whisked" x)
    |> List.reduce (fun a b -> sprintf "%s, plus %s" a b)
```

When you whisk `"70<g> of egg yolks"`, you get `"70<g> of egg yolks, whisked"`. Then when you whisk that together with `"100<g> of granulated sugar"` and `"120<ml> of sweet marsala wine"`, you get the output:

```
"70<g> of egg yolks, whisked, plus 100<g> of granulated sugar, whisked, plus 120<ml> of sweet marsala wine, whisked"
```

And yet your function is beautifully simple (just three lines to handle any *number* of ingredients!) and you didn't have to write any of the list-handling code, since that was taken care of by the standard F# core library functions `List.map` and `List.reduce`. **That** sort of elegance is what you should be aiming for when you do functional programming.

#### Fold and reduce

I said I'd explain the difference between `fold` and `reduce`. The main difference is whether you expect to be dealing with empty collections sometimes. The `reduce` function *requires* that there be at least one item in the collection you're reducing, and doesn't need an initial value since the first item of the collection is taken as the initial value. But because `reduce` needs the first item of the collection to set its initial value, it will throw an exception if it is passed an empty collection, because there's no way for it to know what value to use. (F# *deliberately* avoids `null`, for good reason -- so it's not always possible to determine a good value for an empty collection). Whereas `fold` requires you to specify an explicit initial value, but it is okay with an empty collection, because if you pass an empty collection then it just returns the default value. E.g.,

```
let zeroInts = []
let oneInt   = [1]
let twoInts  = [1; 2]

let add x y = x + y

zeroInts |> List.reduce add  // Error
oneInt   |> List.reduce add  // Result: 1
twoInts  |> List.reduce add  // Result: 3
zeroInts |> List.fold add 0  // No error, result: 0
oneInt   |> List.fold add 0  // Result: 1
twoInts  |> List.fold add 0  // Result: 3
```

See also [Difference between fold and reduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055837/difference-between-fold-and-reduce) for more explanations.

Comment: I started writing my own answer after saying tl;dr to yours. After answering with "you should pass a list of ingredients and then call a reduce", I have actually your answer and... well, it's a very good one and also a reason I did not post mine. Can you maybe just include TL;DR in the beginning to make your intent clear right from the start?

Comment: I tend to write answers in "teaching" mode, meaning to move from the bad example to the good example. But you're right that some people may see a long answer and just skip it; I'll add an executive summary at the top. Good idea.

Comment: I am getting an error when I compile the following:

    open System    
    type Ingredient = string
    // Ingredients.
    let eggYolks = "70<g> of egg yolks."
    let granulatedSugar = "100<g> of granulated sugar."
    let marsalaWine = "120<ml> of sweet marsala wine."    
    let whisk (ingredients : Ingredient list) =
        ingredients
        |> List.map (fun x -> sprintf "%s, whisked" x)
        |> List.reduce (fun a b -> sprintf "%s, plus %s" a b)
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let mixture = whisk [eggYolks; granulatedSugar; marsalaWine]

What am I missing?

Comment: @matekus EntryPointAttribute annotates an entrypoint function that has to return an integer. let mixture ... is not such function. Furthermore, I think that let mixture = ... does not actually cause the whisking to evaluate, it merely assigns a name to a function that calls whisk with the parameters you specified. Use this: [<EntryPoint>] (newline)
`let main argv = (newline)
    let mixture = whisk [eggYolks; granulatedSugar; marsalaWine](newline)
    printfn "%s" mixture(newline)
    0(newline)` and replace (newline) with the actual newline. Last statement (0 here) is return value in F#