# haskell io stream memory

Tags: haskell, memory-management, memory-leaks

I try to parse large log files in haskell. I'm using `System.IO.Streams` but it seems to eat a lot of memory when I fold over the input. Here are two (ugly) examples:

First load 1M `Int` to memory in a list.

```
let l = foldl (\aux p -> p:aux) [] [1..1000000]
return (sum l)
```

Memory consumption is beautiful. Ints eat 3Mb and the list needs 6Mb:

[see memory consumption of building list of 1M Int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2b34.png)

Then try the same with Stream of ByteStrings. We need an ugly back and forth conversation but I don't think makes any difference

```
let s = Streams.fromList $ map (B.pack . show) [1..1000000]

l <-  s >>= 
      Streams.map bsToInt  >>=
      Streams.fold (\aux p -> p:aux) [] 

return (sum l)
```

[see memory consumption of building a list of Ints from a stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ6xT.png)

Why does it need more memory? And it's even worse if I read it from a file. It needs 90Mb

```
result <- withFileAsInput file load
putStrLn $ "loaded " ++ show result
where load is = do
        l <- Streams.lines is >>= 
             Streams.map bsToInt  >>=
             Streams.fold (\aux p -> p:aux) [] 

        return (sum l)
```

My assumption is Streams.fold has some issues. Because the library's built in countInput method doesn't use it. Any idea?

**EDIT**

after investigation I reduced the question to this: why does this code needs an extra 50Mb?

```
do
  let l = map (Builder.toLazyByteString . intDec ) [1..1000000]
  let l2 = map (fst . fromJust . B.readInt) l
  return (foldl' (\aux p -> p:aux) [] l2)
```

without the conversions it only needs 30Mb, with the conversions 90Mb.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, the `foldl (\aux p -> p:aux) []` is redundant. It constructs a list with the same elements as the list it takes as an argument! Without the redundancy, the example is equivalent to `sum [1..1000000]` or `foldl (+) 0 [1..1000000]`. Also, it would be better to use the strict left fold `foldl'` to avoid the accumulation of reducible expressions on the heap. See [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) on the Haskell wiki.

In your last example, you are using `System.IO.Streams.Combinators.fold` for building a list of all the integers which are read from the file, and then try to sum the list like you did in your first example.

The problem is that, because of the sequencing of file read operations imposed by the `IO` monad, *all* the data in the file has been read before you start summing the list, and is lurking on the heap, possibly still untransformed from the original Strings and taking even *more* memory.

The solution is to perform the actual sum *inside* the fold as each new element arrives; that way you don't need to have the full list in memory at any time, only the current element (being able to do this while performing I/O is one of the aims of streaming libraries). And the fold provided by `io-streams` is strict, analogous to `foldl'`. So you don't accumulate reducible expressions on the heap, either.

Try something like `System.IO.Streams.Combinators.fold (+) 0`.

Comment: `foldl (\aux p -> p:aux) []` is not always redundant. Try `take 20 $ foldl (\aux p -> p:aux) [] [1..]` vs `take 20 $ [1..]`.

Comment: @bennofs You are correct. There is a difference when dealing with infinite lists.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists

Comment: Maybe I was just wrong and the problem comes from converting int to bytestring and then back. I compared the two solutions `foldl (\aux p -> p:aux) [] $ map (bsToInt . iToBs) [1..1000000]` and without conversion. An extra 40Mb appears if I have bytestring.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem was the lazy creation of `ByteString`s and not with the iterator.
See 
[Why creating and disposing temporal ByteStrings eats up my memory in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350177/why-creating-and-disposing-temporal-bytestrings-eats-up-my-memory-in-haskell)