# Haskell - What does the lambda in this primality test mean and how does this work?

Tags: haskell, primes, lambda, primality-test

From http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Testing_primality, there is this code:

```
isPrime n = n > 1 &&
    foldr (\p r -> p*p > n || ((n `rem` p) /= 0 && r)) True primes
```

Where primes is a list of prime numbers (possibly infinite).

Two questions:

1. How would one read the lambda passed to `foldr` function
2. Since `foldr` starts from the right, why does this function work when it is passed an infinite list of primes?  I'm guessing there is a short circuit built into the lambda?

Comment: [foldl versus foldr behavior with infinite lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3082324/791604)

Comment: You ask, "How would one translate the lambda?". I ask, "Translate to what?".

Comment: thx, edited for clarification.  +1 for the link -- I still hadn't quite internalized how the folds work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folds might be easy to grasp visually:

```
   foldr g z [a,b,c...,x] === g a (g b (g c (g ... (g x z) ... )))
```

So if `g p r` doesn't use its 2nd arg, it won't force any further list access. Like you said, because of the short-circuit behaviour of `||` ("logical or").

And `foldl g z [a,b,c...,x] === (g ... (g (g (g z a) b) c) ... x)`.

To read the function, first we notice that the fold is applied to a list of primes, `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17..]`. So it can be read as

```hs
isPrime n = n > 1 &&
   foldr (\p r -> p*p > n || ((n `rem` p) /= 0 && r)) True primes
===
isPrime n = n > 1 &&
   (2*2 > n || (rem n 2 /= 0 &&
   (3*3 > n || (rem n 3 /= 0 &&
   (5*5 > n || (rem n 5 /= 0 && 
   -- the expansion stops when p*p > n
   -- because (True || r) === True
   ......................... && 
   (True) ... ))))))
```

In `foldr`'s combining function, the second argument is for "result" of folding the rest of the list; `r` is a suggestive name to that effect.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it gives a clearer explanation of how the fold and the lamdba work in this function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Lazy evaluation means boolean short-circuit logic stops a chain of functions being evaluated, even where the logic is inside the functions.

As a simple example, for any Foldable data type, you can write a `null` function like this:

```
null t = foldr (\x b -> False && b) True t
```

This function will never be called more than once, because for an instance with more than one element it will evaluate to

```
False && *thunk* foldr...
```

The short-circuit boolean **and** means that the thunk is never evaluated, so this will happily work with infinite structures.  Which is why you shouldn't implement `null` as a check to see if `size == 0`

This doesn't work in a strict language; each iterations of foldr would be evaluated in turn and passed to the next.

As for the lambda...

```
isPrime n = n > 1 &&
    foldr (\p r -> p*p > n || ((n `rem` p) /= 0 && r)) True primes
```

could be written like this:

```
isPrime n = n > 1 &&
    foldr f True primes
    where
        f p r = p*p > n || ((n `rem` p) /= 0 && r)
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: If it wasn't clear, the short-circuit boolean **or** `||` in that function works in the same way as the simpler example above.

Comment: This is a good explanation of the fold, but I think the answer that I've accepted is a better illustration of how exactly the fold and the lambda work in this case.

Comment: Well, I started out by saying it's about short circuit boolean logic and there's a big `||` slap in the middle of that lambda ;)

Comment: And before your update, it wasn't at all clear what you meant by "how does the lambda work?".  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda part looks like this being translated into pythonish pseudocode:

```
def f(p, r):
  # invariant: r is True iff we have not seen a divisor of n yet.
  # we must return an updated r

  if p > sqrt(n): 
     return True # because we need a divisor less than that

  if p does not divide n and r is True:
     return True # because p is not a divisor neither we have seen one yet

  return False  # and this will become a new r and will return False forever.
```

As for the `foldr` part, that's tricky indeed. `foldr` [first evaluates the result for the tail](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#foldr) of the list (`r`) then applies the function to the head and that `r`. So there must be a point where the tail can be computed without going further.

That will happen when the head is at least `sqrt(n)`, which means: if there's a divisor, you can find it before, but for now return True and don't evaluate the tail.

Comment: I'd prefer `if p does not divide n: return r`. -- About `foldr`: Haskell is lazy, so actually `r` is not computed prior to calling the combining function for the first time. An attempt to compute `r`'s value will only be made if `r`'s value is requested.