# Infinite list in haskell combined with fold* doesn't calculate

Tags: haskell, dictionary, infinite, fold

Let's say I want to get a sorted infinite list of all primepowers up to exponent `n`.

I have got a function to merge two sorted lists and a function that gives me primes.

```
merge :: Ord t => [t] -> [t] -> [t]
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | (x <= y) = x : merge xs (y:ys)
    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys

primes :: [Integer]
primes = sieve [2..]
    where
        sieve [] = []
        sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve (filter (\x -> x `mod` p /= 0) xs)
```

I have two versions of the `listOfPrimepowers` function:

```
primepowers :: Integer -> [Integer]
primepowers n = foldr (merge) [] (listOfPrimepowers n)    

-- terminating
listOfPrimepowers' n = map(\x -> (map(\y -> y ^ x) primes)) [1..n]

-- non terminating    
listOfPrimepowers'' n = map(\x -> (map(\y -> x ^ y) [1..n])) primes
```

One delivers the correct result and the other one doesn't. The only difference is, that the first version maps the primepowers in a way like `[[2,3,5,7, ...],[4,9,25,...]]` and the second version maps the primepowers like `[[2,4,8],[3,9,27],[5,25,125], ...]`. You see, the infinity is at another level in the list.

Do you have an explanation why the 2nd function doesn't produce any output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [foldl versus foldr behavior with infinite lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Sorry, I did mean to use foldr in the second code extract ... But it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is caused by `foldr merge` having to look through all the lists to find the minimal element at the head of one of the lists. If `foldr merge` is given a infinite list of finite lists, `foldr merge` cannot ever compute the first element of the list - it keeps looking for the minimal element of the rest of the list of lists, before it can compare it to the first element of the first list - `2`. On the other hand, if `foldr merge` is given a finite list of infinite lists, `foldr merge` can determine the first element of the merged list, and moves on to the next one. That way you can produce an arbitrary number of elements in the first case, but not a single one in the second case.

---

Let's expand `foldr merge []`:

```
foldr merge [] (xs0:xs1:xs2:...:[]) =
merge xs0 (merge xs1 (merge xs2 (merge xs3 ... [])))
```

Clearly, if `(xs0:xs1:xs2:...:[])` is infinite, the "nested" calls to merge will form an infinite chain. But what about haskell being "lazy"? `primes` is also defined in terms of itself, yet it produces output? Well, there is actually a rule of `foldr`: it can produce output for infinite lists only if the function passed to `foldr` is not strict in its second argument - i.e. sometimes it can produce output without having to evaluate the result of `foldr` for the rest of the list.

The `merge` pattern-matches the second argument - that alone can cause non-termination - and uses a strict function `<=`, so `merge` is strict in the second argument, and the infinite chain will have to evaluate the first element of every list before the top level `merge` can produce any result.

Because `merge` is strict, and because `merge` is associative, you can - and should - use `foldl'` instead of `foldr` to merge the finite list of infinite lists.

Comment: Thanks, this perfectly answers my question!

Comment: `foldr` or `foldl'` is secondary. Both won't help with the 2nd at all, and with the 1st, it's unclear which is better - `foldr` will use more stack to start producing but will build a better structure which will be working faster, with much less overhead.

Comment: @WillNess what makes the structure built by `foldr` better?

Comment: I write about it in my answer (at the end). :)

Comment: @WillNess I think I do mention `foldl'` must be used only for finite lists of infinite lists (ie can't be used with variant 2), so I hope we are clear on that. I added the question on efficiency in your answer

Comment: there is an issue with foldr with strict merge: it will eat a lot of stack to produce its first number. It can even cause a stack overflow for a very long list. foldl' should run in constant stack. Fortunately, so will foldr with non-strict merge (if it is possible to use it).

Answer (score 2):

You can make both variants work, fairly easily. The technique involved is worth knowing.

Your code is equivalent to

```
primepowers n = 
  foldr merge [] 
      -- terminating:
 --   [[p^k | p <- primes]  | k <- [1..n]]  -- n infinite lists

      -- non terminating:
      [[p^k | k <- [1..n]]  | p <- primes]  -- infinite list of n-length lists
```

[*"Naturally, taking the minimum of an infinite list is non-terminating"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22860015/849891) is the truth, and only the truth, but it is not the whole truth, here.

Here, the infinite list `primes` is *already sorted* in increasing order of its elements. So the heads of the lists `[p^k | k <- [1..n]]` are sorted and increasing, and the lists themselves are sorted and increasing too. *Based on this knowledge* alone, we can right away produce the head element of the merged streams — the minimum of the infinite list of heads of all these lists — in O(1) time, without actually inspecting *any* of them, except the very first one (which is the answer, itself).

Your problem is thus solved by using the following function instead of `merge`, in the `foldr` expression:

```
imerge (x:xs) ys = x : merge xs ys
```

(as seen in the code by Richard Bird in [the article by Melissa O'Neill](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf)). Now both variants will just work. `imerge` is non-strict in its 2nd argument and is naturally used with `foldr`, even with finite lists.

Using `foldl` instead of `foldr` is plain wrong with the 2nd variant, because `foldl` on an infinite list is non-terminating.

Using `foldl` with the 1st variant, though possible (since the list itself is finite), is suboptimal here: it will place the more frequently-producing streams at the bottom of the overall chain of merges, i.e. it will run slower than the one with `foldr`.

see also: [folds on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Evaluation_order_considerations).

Comment: what do you mean - "at the bottom of the overall chain of merges"? If merging has to inspect heads of all lists, why would it matter where the "most frequently-producing stream" is? I ceratinly learned from your answer, even though I realise it is sorted both ways, but the question was about the existing `merge`, so I didn't consider other ways.

Comment: Each new number  has to "percolate up" through all the binary `merge` nodes on its way to the top node. Because of laziness, after the very first number is produced, each binary `merge` node remembers the head of its argument which did not produce the number on previous step.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you illustrate it? It seems to me that in both cases the `merge` will use one list from "the" list, and one list constructed from preceding or succeeding folds. In both cases one needs to "percolate" the head of the list with the minimal element somewhere.

Comment: I imagine to myself a degenerate tree of binary merge nodes. It is either skewed to the left (produced by foldl) or to the right (by foldr). e.g. `(((a+b)+c)+d)+e`. The top (here, rightmost) `+` will pull one of its inputs on each yield (except on the very first if will pull both). We know that numbers yielded by `a` will have to go through all the `+`s. In `a+(...)` they will have to go only through 1 such node.

Comment: this is discussed at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Linear_merging. [Empirically it indeed shows](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Segmented) if foldl is used instead of foldr, it becomes much slower.

Comment: and then there's [tree-like folding...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Tree-like_folds) :)

Comment: (to your first comment) yes, your answer provides an explanation of the problem, and I wanted to add more about what can be done about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The second version does not give you any output because the input is an infinite list of lists. If you think about it, `foldr merge []` creates a *sorted* list from a list of lists, therefore the head element of the resulting list will be the *minimum* of all the head elements of the lists. Naturally, taking the minimum of an infinite list is non-terminating, so the function doesn't even get to the point when the first element of the result becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your functions will terminated

The first thing is that `primes` is an infinite list. That means the comprehension of the program dwells in its lazy evaluation

for the first function

```
primepowers :: Integer -> [Integer]
primepowers n = foldr (merge) [] (listOfPrimepowers n)    

listOfPrimepowers n = map (\x -> (map (\y -> y ^ x) primes)) [1..n]
```

will not terminated because. Even if the outer map is apply to a finite list [1..n] each `\x`  consume by the inner `map` is apply on an infinite list `primes`.

The second function

```
primepowers :: Integer -> [Integer]
primepowers n = foldl (merge) [] (listOfPrimepowers n)

listOfPrimepowers n = map(\x -> (map(\y -> x ^ y) [1..n])) primes
```

will not terminate because the outer `map` is apply directly on an infinite list `primes`

Comment: I see your point. But I'm not interested in termination, I'm interested in some (infinite) output.
The first version produces output while the second doesn't return any.