# Haskell - List comprehension with infinite lists

Tags: list, haskell

This is the piece of code

```
primepowers n = foldr merge [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..n] ]  -- (1)

merge::(Ord t) =>[t]->[t]->[t]
merge x [] = x
merge [] y = y
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x < y = x:merge xs (y:ys)
    | otherwise = y:merge (x:xs) ys
```

which is equal to the mathematical expression *`{p^i | p is prime, 1 <= i <= n}`*.

`prime` returns an infinite list of prime numbers. What I am interested is in the evaluation of `(1)`.
These are my thoughts:

If we first just look at `[ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..3] ]` this would return an infinite list of `[[2,3,5,7,9,...],...]`. But as we know `p^1` (p is prime) never ends, Haskell will never evaluate `[p^2]` and `[p^3]`. Is this just because it is an infinite list or because of lazy evaluation?

Let's carry on with merge:
merge will return `[2,3,5,7,9,11,...]` because again we still have an infinite list or because of some other reason?

Now to `foldr`:
`foldr` starts evaluating from back. Here with specifically ask for the rightmost element, which is a infinite list `[p^3]`.
So the evaluation would be like this

```
merge (merge (merge [] [p^3]) [p^2]) [p^1]
```

But we should not forget that these lists are infinite, so how does Haskell deal with that fact?

Could anyone explain me the evaluation process of the above function?

Comment: One good way to see when something gets evaluated is to use the `Debug.Trace` module.

Comment: You can not use foldr on infinite lists because it will search forever for the last element.

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic, that's not true. Try `foldr const 0 [1..]`

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists

Comment: for some background, cf. http://joerg.endrullis.de/research.html#productivity

Comment: The foldr is only over a finite list - `i <- [1..n]`

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to define it as

```
primepowers n = foldr (\(x:xs) r-> x:merge xs r) 
                      [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..n] ]
```

<sup>(as seen in Richard Bird's code in the article [O'Neill, Melissa E., "The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes"](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf)).</sup>

The lists to the right of a current one all start with bigger numbers, there's no chance of their merged list ever producing a value smaller or equal to the current list's head, so it can be produced unconditionally.

That way it will also explore only as many of the internal streams as needed:

```
GHCi> let pps_list = [ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..42] ]
GHCi> :sprint pps_list
pps_list = _
GHCi> take 20 $ foldr (\(x:xs) r-> x:merge xs r) [] pps_list
[2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,16,17,19,23,25,27,29,31,32,37,41]
GHCi> :sprint pps_list
pps_list = (2 : 3 : 5 : 7 : 11 : 13 : 17 : 19 : 23 : 29 : 31 : 37 :
            41 : _) :
           (4 : 9 : 25 : 49 : _) : (8 : 27 : 125 : _) : (16 : 81 : _) :
           (32 : 243 : _) : (64 : _) : _
```

---

To your question per se, `foldr f z [a,b,c,...,n] = f a (f b (f c (... (f n z)...)))` so (writing `ps_n` for `map (^n) primes`), your expression is equivalent to

```
merge ps (merge ps_2 (merge ps_3 (... (merge ps_n [])...)))
= merge ps r
     where r = merge ps_2 (merge ps_3 (... (merge ps_n [])...))
```

because you use `merge` as your combining function. Notice that the leftmost `merge` springs into action *first*, while the expression for `r` isn't even built yet (because its value wasn't yet *needed* - Haskell's evaluation is *by need*.)

Now, this `merge` demands the head value of both its first and second argument (as written, it actually checks the second argument first, for being `[]`).

The first argument isn't the problem, but the second is the result of folding all the rest of the lists ("r" in `foldr`'s combining function stands for "recursive result"). Thus, each element in the list will be visited and its head element *forced* - and all this just to produce one very first value, the head of the result list, by the leftmost `merge` call...

In my code, the combining function does not at first demand the head of its second argument list. That's what limits its exploration of the whole list of lists, makes it more economic in its demands, and thus more *productive* (it will even work if you just omit the `n` altogether).

---

Your example Haskell expression `[ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..3] ]` returns  *finite* list of length *3*, each element being an infinite list: `[[2,3,5,7,11,...],[4,9,25,...],[8,27,125,...]]` so `foldr` has no problem translating it into `merge [2,3,5,7,11,...] (merge [4,9,25,...] (merge [8,27,125,..] []))`:

> foldr merge [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..3] ] 
>    = merge [2,3,5,7,11,...] *(foldr merge [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [2..3] ])* 
>    = merge [2,3,5,7,11,...] (merge [4,9,25,...] *(foldr merge [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [3..3] ])*) 
>    = merge [2,3,5,7,11,...] (merge [4,9,25,...] (merge [8,27,125,..] *(foldr merge [] [])*)) 
>     = merge [2,3,5,7,11,...] (merge [4,9,25,...] (merge [8,27,125,..] **[]**)) 
>        =  merge [2,3,5,7,11,...] (merge [**4**,9,25,...] [**8**,27,125,..]) 
>        =  merge [**2**,3,5,7,11,...] (**4**:merge [9,25,...] [8,27,125,..]) 
>        =  2:merge [**3**,5,7,11,...] (**4**:merge [9,25,...] [8,27,125,..]) 
>        =  2:3:merge [**5**,7,11,...] (**4**:merge [9,25,...] [8,27,125,..]) 
>        =  2:3:4:merge [5,7,11,...] (merge [**9**,25,...] [**8**,27,125,..]) 
>        =  2:3:4:merge [**5**,7,11,...] (**8**:merge [9,25,...] [27,125,..]) 
>        =  2:3:4:5:merge [**7**,11,...] (**8**:merge [9,25,...] [27,125,..]) 
>       .....

As you can see, the rightmost inner list is examined first, because `merge` is strict in (i.e. demands to know) both its arguments, as explained above. For `[ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..42] ]` it would expand all 42 of them, and examine the heads of all of them, before producing even the head element of the result.

---

With the tweaked function, `mg (x:xs) r = x:merge xs r`, the evaluation proceeds as

> foldr mg [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [1..3] ] 
>    = mg [**2**,3,5,7,11,...] (foldr mg [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [2..3] ]) 
>    = 2:merge [3,5,7,11,...] *(foldr mg [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [2..3] ])* 
>    = 2:merge [3,5,7,11,...] (mg [**4**,9,25,...] 
>                             (foldr mg [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [3..3] ])) 
>    = 2:merge [**3**,5,7,11,...] (**4**:merge [9,25,...] 
>                             (foldr mg [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [3..3] ])) 
>    = 2:3:merge [**5**,7,11,...] (**4**:merge [9,25,...] 
>                             (foldr mg [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [3..3] ])) 
>    = 2:3:4:merge [5,7,11,...] (merge [9,25,...] 
>                             *(foldr mg [] [ map (^i) primes | i <- [3..3] ])*) 
>    = 2:3:4:merge [5,7,11,...] (merge [9,25,...]
>                             (mg [**8**,27,125,..] (foldr mg [] []))) 
>    = 2:3:4:merge [5,7,11,...] (merge [**9**,25,...]
>                             (**8**:merge [27,125,..] (foldr mg [] []))) 
>    = 2:3:4:merge [**5**,7,11,...] (**8**:merge [9,25,...]
>                             (merge [27,125,..] (foldr mg [] []))) 
>    = 2:3:4:5:merge [**7**,11,...] (**8**:merge [9,25,...]
>                             (merge [27,125,..] (foldr mg [] [])))  
>    .....

so it starts producing the results much sooner, without expanding much of the inner lists. This just follows the definition of `foldr`,

```
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

where, because of the laziness, `(foldr f z xs)` is not evaluated right away *if* `f` does not demand its value (or a part of it, like its *head*).

Comment: That `sprint` is a neat tool I never seem to remember to use. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 3):

The lists being merged are infinite, but that doesn't matter.

What matters is that you only have a finite number of lists being merged, and so to compute the next element of the merge you only need to perform a finite number of comparisons.

To compute the head of `merge xs ys` you only need to compute the head of `xs` and the head of `ys`. So by induction, if you have a finite tree of `merge` operations, you can compute the head of the overall merge in finite time.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that `merge` needs to completely scan its whole input lists to produce its whole output. However, the key point is that every element in the output depends only from *finite prefixes* of the input lists.

For instance, consider `take 10 (map (*2) [1..])`. To compute the first 10 elements, you do not need to examine the whole `[1..]`. Indeed, `map` will not scan the whole infinite list and "after that" start returning the output: if it behaved like that, it would simply hang on infinite lists. This "streaming" property of `map` is given by laziness and the `map` definition

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = x : map f xs
```

The last line reads "yield x, and *then* proceed with the rest", so the caller gets to inspect `x` before `map` produces its whole output. By comparison

```
map f xs = go xs []
  where go []     acc = acc
        go (x:xs) acc = go xs (acc ++ [f x])
```

would be another definition of `map` which would start generating its output only after its input has been consumed. It is equivalent on finite lists (performance aside), but not equivalent on infinite ones (hangs on infinite lists).

If you want to empirically test that your `merge` is indeed working lazily, try this:

```
take 10 $ merge (10:20:30:error "end of 1") (5:15:25:35:error "end of 2")
```

Feel free to play by changing the constants. You will see an exception being printed on screen, but only after a few list elements have already been produced by `merge`.

Answer (score 2):

`[map (^i) primes | i <- [1..3]]` returns just `thunk`. Nothing is evaluated for now. You could try this:

```
xs = [x | x <- [1..], error ""]

main = print $ const 0 xs
```

This program prints `0`, so `error ""` wasn't evaluated here.

You can think about `foldr` being defined like this:

```
foldr f z  []    = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f xs)
```

Then

```
primepowers n = foldr merge [] [map (^i) primes | i <- [1..3]]
```

evaluates like this (after it was forced):

```
merge thunk1 (merge thunk2 (merge thunk3 []))
```

where `thunkn` is a suspended computation of primes in n-th power. Now the first `merge` forces evaluation of `thunk1` and `merge thunk2 (merge thunk3 [])`, which are evaluated to weak head normal forms (whnf). Forcing `merge thunk2 (merge thunk3 [])` causes forcing `thunk2` and `merge thunk3 []`. `merge thunk3 []` reduces to `thunk3` and then `thunk3` is forced. So the expression becomes

```
merge (2 : thunk1') (merge (4 : thunk2') (8 : thunk3'))
```

Which, due to the definition of merge, reduces to

```
merge (2 : thunk1') (4 : merge thunk2' (8 : thunk3')
```

And again:

```
2 : merge thunk1' (4 : merge thunk2' (8 : thunk3')
```

Now `merge` forces `thunk1'`, but not the rest of the expression, because it's already in whnf

```
2 : merge (3 : thunk1'') (4 : merge thunk2' (8 : thunk3)
2 : 3 : merge thunk1'' (4 : merge thunk2' (8 : thunk3')
2 : 3 : merge (5 : thunk1''') (4 : merge thunk2' (8 : thunk3')
2 : 3 : 4 : merge (5 : thunk1''') (merge thunk2' (8 : thunk3')
2 : 3 : 4 : merge (5 : thunk1''') (merge (9 : thunk2'') (8 : thunk3')
2 : 3 : 4 : merge (5 : thunk1''') (8 : merge (9 : thunk2'') thunk3')
2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : merge thunk1''' (8 : merge (9 : thunk2'') thunk3')
...
```

Intuitively, only those values become evaluated, that are needed. Read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) for a better explanation.

---

You can also merge infinite list of infinite lists. The simplest way would be:

```
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs

primepowers = foldr1 interleave [map (^i) primes | i <- [1..]]
```

The `interleave` function interleaves two infinite lists, for example, `interleave [1,3..] [2,4..]` is equal to `[1..]`. So `take 20 primepowers` gives you `[2,4,3,8,5,9,7,16,11,25,13,27,17,49,19,32,23,121,29,125]`. But this list is unordered, we can do better.

`[map (^i) primes | i <- [1..]]` reduces to

```
[[2,3,5...]
,[4,9,25...]
,[8,27,125...]
...
]
```

We have the precondition, that in every n-th list there are elements, that are smaller, than head of the (n+1)-th list. We can extract such elements from the first list (`2` and `3` are smaller than `4`), and now we have this:

```
[[5,7,11...]
,[4,9,25...]
,[8,27,125...]
...
]
```

The precondition doesn't hold, so we must fix this and swap the first list and the second:

```
[[4,9,25...]
,[5,7,11...]
,[8,27,125...]
...
]
```

Now we extract `4` and swap the first list and the second:

```
[[5,7,11...]
,[9,25,49...]
,[8,27,125...]
...
]
```

But the precondition doesn't hold, since there are elements in the second list (`9`), that are not smaller than the head of the third list (`8`). So we do the same trick again:

```
[[5,7,11...]
,[8,27,125...]
,[9,25,49...]
...
]
```

And now we can extract elements again. Repeating the process infinitely gives us ordered list of prime powers. Here is the code:

```
swap xs@(x:_) xss = xss1 ++ xs : xss2 where
    (xss1, xss2) = span ((< x) . head) xss 

mergeAll (xs:xss@((x:_):_)) = xs1 ++ mergeAll (swap xs2 xss) where
    (xs1, xs2) = span (< x) xs

primepowers = mergeAll [map (^i) primes | i <- [1..]]
```

For example, `take 20 primepowers` is equal to `[2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,16,17,19,23,25,27,29,31,32,37,41]`.

This is probably not the nicest way to obtaining ordered list of prime powers, but it's fairly easy one.

**EDIT**

Look at the **Will Ness**' answer for a better solution, which is both easier and nicer.

Comment: Ok. We have the expression [[2,3,5,7,...],[4,9,25,49,..],[8,27,125,...],...].
But from here now, I am not understanding it.
What happens from here on
**foldr merge [] [[2,3,5,7,...],[4,9,25,49,..],[8,27,125,...],...]**?
I am not getting it. Sry :(

Comment: @user3237465 the real treat with folding is that we can [fold the lists in the shape of a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Tree-like_folds). It might force more of the internal lists' heads, but it should be significantly faster overall. In terms of your solution, `swap` and `mergeAll` perform *linear* search with the `span`, so turning the *visited-lists* list into a priority queue should be beneficial... -- (Also, here there are no duplicates, and your code would loop if they were, but it's easy to fix: just use `span (<= x)` in `mergeAll`.)

Comment: @Will Ness, I experimented a bit more, and the fastest code was just `primepowers = foldr1 (\(x:xs) rs -> x : merge xs rs) [map (^i) primes | i <- [1..]]`. I've stolen a priority queue (here is my ugly code: http://ideone.com/yHd5Ao , it's possible to optimize it further, however) and tried the `mergeAll` function from the `Data.List.Ordered` package. But maybe I'm doing something wrong, or maybe constants are too big in the optimized solutions. And since my solution is rather ad hoc, I prefer to use `(<)`, because this `=` would make mess in the semantics.

Comment: great; of course each problem has its own best fit solution. for primes, tree folding (with `foldi`) is definitely much faster than `foldr`. perhaps here it doesn't matter because there are no duplicates. -- about the <=, there is no difference at all when there are no duplicates in the input; and if there are, the code with < will just loop indefinitely. Just try `take 10 $ mergeAll [[1..],[2..]]`.

Comment: @Will Ness, there is difference in semantics. I read `<=` like "there are equal elements".