# How do I write takeWhile using foldl?

Tags: list, haskell, fold

So I am doing exercises from real world haskell book and I wrote following code for takeWhile function using foldl.

```
myTakeWhile' :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myTakeWhile' f xs = foldl step [] xs
    where step x xs | f x       = x:(myTakeWhile' f xs)
                    | otherwise = []
```

This gives the following error, which I am unable to understand.

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for myTakeWhile' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
          at p1.hs:17:17
    Expected type: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
      Actual type: a -> [a] -> [a]
    Relevant bindings include
      step :: a -> [a] -> [a] (bound at p1.hs:19:11)
      xs :: [a] (bound at p1.hs:18:16)
      f :: a -> Bool (bound at p1.hs:18:14)
      myTakeWhile' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] (bound at p1.hs:18:1)
    In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘step’
    In the expression: foldl step [] xs
```

Comment: Are you sure the exercise doesn't ask you to use `foldr`? Implementing `takeWhile` using `foldl` makes no sense. Implementing it with `foldr` is relatively simple.

Comment: The exercise didn't mention which fold to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Edit

1) Your main error, is that you are not understanding that `fold` does the recursion for you, you don't have to self reference the function `myTakeWhile'`, also, fold has another type:

```
foldl: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

your type error in the step function on where clause is because of it.

2) Your second error, because of the definition of `foldl`, your `takeWhile` will be created from the end to the beginning, so, you should have to reverse the list **(all this only because you are asking how to do it with foldl)**

You can do this by using a simple `lambda` and an `if else`, is a little more readable:

```
myTakeWhile' f xs = foldl (\rs x -> if f x then x:rs else []) [] (reverse xs)
```

example:

```
myTakeWhile' (<10) [1..20]
```

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

However, with this, you just can't go over infinite list, like this:

```
myTakeWhile' (<10) [1..]
```

It will hangs trying to create all the unevaluated expression.

Anyway, if you want to use `guards` and `where`, you should do it like this:

```
myTakeWhile f xs = foldl step [] (reverse xs)
  where step rs x | f x = x : rs
                  | otherwise = []
```

**3) Most important of all:**

As @amalloy says, `takeWhile` is much more suitable if you implement it by using **`foldr`** :). Understand the differences between the two is crucial in some cases one using one or another can cause you **performance** issues, for that, you can read this question:

[foldl versus foldr behavior with infinite lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists)

**4) Finally, the correct alternative using `foldr`:**

```
myTakeWhile'' f xs = foldr (\x rs -> if f x then x:rs else []) [] xs
```

with this, you can use infinite list:

```
myTakeWhile' (<10) [1..]
```

You can see the difference of how it makes the folds like this:

```
Prelude> foldr (\x y -> concat ["(",x,"+",y,")"]) "0" (map show [1..13])
"(1+(2+(3+(4+(5+(6+(7+(8+(9+(10+(11+(12+(13+0)))))))))))))"

Prelude> foldl (\x y -> concat ["(",x,"+",y,")"]) "0" (map show [1..13])
"(((((((((((((0+1)+2)+3)+4)+5)+6)+7)+8)+9)+10)+11)+12)+13)"
```

This sources from https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold

Comment: This implements `filter`, not `takeWhile`.

Comment: `myTakeWhile' f xs = foldr (\x rs  -> if f x then x:rs else []) [] xs` works, although i wanted to know what is wrong in the where step expression that i have written

Comment: You should also mention that `foldl` is the wrong fold to use for `takeWhile`: `foldr` is much more suitable.

Comment: @amalloy that's also true, I will mention, thanks a lot again!

Comment: @PiyushDivyankar , I made an important edit to the answer that you should be looking at, that's why you had the errors using foldl

Comment: @amalloy, I made another edit, that's why you were talking about when you said "more suitable"?

Comment: Try your `foldr` version like this: `takeWhile' (< 10) [1..]`, and then try the same thing with your `foldl` version.

Comment: @amalloy I got the point, not need to try... mmm, I will take another rid on it.... Very good point

Comment: `foldl` is never productive on infinite lists, while `foldr` can be if the folding function is non-strict in its second argument.

Comment: @amalloy aaaaah, I can see now, I was breaking my brain, but it was worth the time! So, the approach with a non infinite list, using reverse with foldl, is valid?

Comment: I mean, sure, it will work, but it is strictly worse for no good reason.

Comment: @amalloy I really really grateful, I learned a lot of things with your comments!