# Intercalate using fold

Tags: function, haskell, fold

Can someone explain me how to write the `intercalate` function using fold? Additionally, I've heard of `foldr` or `foldl`; which of these is the most appropriate to use in this context?

Here's my attempt with recursion:

```
intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
intercalate s [] = []
intercalate s [x] = x
intercalate s (x:xs) = x ++ s ++ (intercalate s xs)
```

Comment: if it's lazy (in its list argument), it must only be right fold. `take 10 . intercalate [0] $ repeat [1..3]` must work, as does the original.

Answer (score 6):

Using `foldr1`:

```
intercalate' :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
intercalate' _ [] = []
intercalate' x xs = foldr1 (\a acc -> a ++ x ++ acc) xs
```

This will intercalate values from the *right* with `x` between each element. (Albeit it does this [*lazily*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). – The entire fold isn't evaluated until needed.)

Both `foldr1` and `foldr` are similar in that they fold from the right. The difference lies in that the former doesn't require us to provide a final term while the latter  does require a final term to be provided. This requires us to pattern match for the empty list, otherwise an exception would be thrown.

Indeed, `foldl1` can also accomplish intercalation. However, this is **strongly discouraged** as the left fold will consume input eagerly.

```
intercalate' :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
intercalate' _ [] = []
intercalate' x xs = foldl1 (\acc a -> acc ++ x ++ a) xs
```

---

To further emphasise the preference over the right fold, consider the following composition:

```
take 10 . intercalate' [0] $ repeat [1..3]
```

Looks harmless. But using `foldl1` will eagerly consume the infinite list, not stopping the process.

However, using `foldr1` will evaluate lazily and give the correct result of `[1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2]`. (`intercalate'` will temporarily evaluate `[1..3] ++ [0] ++ (foldr (...) [0] [elem1 ... elemN])` before `take 10` asks for the leading terms and  evaluates the fold.)

*Kudos to [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321853/intercalate-using-fold/55322084#comment97371392_55322084).*

Useful Reading:
[`foldl` versus `foldr` behaviour with infinite lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists)

Comment: `foldr1` "accumulates from the right, and prepends values to the accumulator" ***only if*** the reducer function is strict. Here it processes the list  left-to-right, splicing the recursive result (not "accumulator", so `r` or similar is the correct mnemonic, not `acc`) in-place on the fly. and left fold is ***absolutely the wrong tool here***, it destroys laziness: `take 10 . intercalate [0] $ repeat [1..3]` must work, as the original does.

Comment: @WillNess "only if the reducer function is strict" – Ah, so due to laziness, the result will end up being a whole chain of `elem0 ++ x ++ elem1 ++ x + elem2 ++ x ++ ... ++ x ++ elemN` and then that gets evaluated when it's needed? (Good catch, btw.)

Comment: with the right fold, yes. and no, not even that: actually it will be `elem0 ++ x ++ (foldr (...) x [elem1....])`. it's a good mnemonic to write it like you did but it is even lazier than that. (you still have the wrong explanation there about `foldr` "accumulating" btw..., and the use of left fold must be discouraged much more strongly, IMO)

Comment: the `n` in `foldr g n xs` is *not* the initial term, but a final one, if `g` is not strict in its second argument. the `r` in `foldr` does not mean it folds ***from*** the right -- that is decided by the semantics of `g` alone. at the most we can say that foldr folds *on* the right or *to* the right. when `g` is lazy (like in this answer) "folds beginning from the last element" is wrong. Instead, it "folds ending on the last element". `foldr g n (x:xs) == g x (foldr g n xs)`, and that's that.

Comment: @WillNess Ach semantics. I guess I still have loads to learn. Thanks for eagerly evaluating my answer. :D

Comment: I'm sorry to be pestering you, but: `foldl` does *not* "perform eager evaluation". in fact it's its major drawback that it isn't (`foldl'` does that, and should be used instead "almost always"). `foldl` does consume the input list eagerly though (and it doesn't evaluate the reducer functions chain that it builds until the whole list has been traversed). ---- yeah, you'll get there with time, and effort. :)

Comment: Haha, no worries. The precision is all good. Also makes for a good learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

Let's remind ourselves about the signature of `foldl`:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

A simple rewrite of what you wrote:

```
intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
intercalate s [] = []
intercalate s [x] = x
intercalate s (x:xs) = foldl (\acc y -> acc ++ s ++ y) x xs
```

Comment: This definition doesn't compile: 'different number of arguments'.

Comment: @bradrn This is what I get for writing code without testing it... :P

Comment: That certainly sounds familiar!

Comment: `foldl` destroys laziness, left-nested `(++)` destroys efficiency. double ungood.