# Why the foldr function gives me a negative result when the list contains a zero?

Tags: haskell, fold

Here an example to illustrate what I mean

```
Prelude> foldr (-) 0 [0,1]  
-1
```

I thought here it would basically do `0 - 0 = 0; 1 - 0 = 1;` but the actual result is `-1`

I tried it with other examples

```
Prelude> foldr (-) 1 [1,3]   
-1

Prelude> foldr (-) 1 [1,9]
-7
```

I probably misunderstood how foldr works so I would be happy about an explanation :)

Comment: See also [foldl versus foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3082324/791604), [List folds as structural transformations](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold#List_folds_as_structural_transformations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `foldr (-) 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. You should get `3`. That's because the fold is equivalent to `(1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - (5 - 0)))))` -- it's starting from the right. If you try `foldl`, you should get `-15`. That's because it's starting from the left and is equivalent to `(((((0 - 1) - 2) - 3) - 4) - 5)`.

Your shorter example, `foldr (-) 0 [0, 1]`, is equivalent to `0 - (1 - 0)`, which reduces to `-1`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I go it now 

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following function:

```hs
printfoldr f init xs = foldr (\el acc -> "(" ++ el ++ f ++ acc ++ ")") (show init) $ map show xs
```

This function simulates how the `foldr` function expands and outputs its string representation.

Let's run a few tests:

```
λ> printfoldr "-" 0 [1,2,3,4]
"(1-(2-(3-(4-0))))"

-- the test cases you provided
λ> printfoldr "-" 0 [1,2]
"(1-(2-0))" -- This reduces to -1 which is the result you had

λ> printfoldr "-" 1 [1,3]
"(1-(3-1))" -- This reduces to -1 which is also the result you had

λ> printfoldr "-" 1 [1,9]
"(1-(9-1))" -- reduces -7 which is also correct
```

So in general, [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) with type `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` works as follows:

```
x0 `f` (x1 `f` ...(xn-2 `f` (xn-1 `f` (xn `f` init))))
```

where `f` is of type `(a -> b -> b)`, `x` is of type `a` and `init` is of type `b`.

Answer (score 2):

`foldr` is defined as follows:

```
foldr f b [] = b
foldr f b (x:xs) = f x (foldr f b xs)
```

You recursively fold the tail of the list, then apply `f` to the head and the recursive result. Note that the base value is used at the *end* of the sequence, not the beginning.

Thinking of it as simply applying the function to one value after another only works if `f` is associative. For example, `1 + (2 + (3 + 0)) == ((1+2) + 3) + 0`.

Subtraction, though, is *not* associative. In general, `x - y - z` is only equal to `(x - y) - z`, not `x - (y - z)`.