# Left and Right Folding over an Infinite list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, infinite, fold

I have issues with the following passage from [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds) (Great book imo, not dissing it):

> One big difference is that right
>   folds work on infinite lists, whereas left ones don't! To put it
>   plainly, if you take an infinite list at some point and you fold it up
>   from the right, you'll eventually reach the beginning of the list.
>   However, if you take an infinite list at a point and you try to fold
>   it up from the left, you'll never reach an end!

I just don't get this. If you take an infinite list and try to fold it up from the right then you'll have to start at the point at infinity, which just isn't happening (If anyone knows of a language where you can do this do tell :p). At least, you'd have to start there according to Haskell's implementation because in Haskell foldr and foldl don't take an argument that determines where in the list they should start folding.

I would agree with the quote iff foldr and foldl took arguments that determined where in the list they should start folding, because it makes sense that if you take an infinite list and start folding right from a defined index it *will* eventually terminate, whereas it doesn't matter where you start with a left fold; you'll be folding towards infinity. However foldr and foldl *do not* take this argument, and hence the quote makes no sense. In Haskell, both a left fold and a right fold over an infinite list **will not terminate**.

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this question in the related column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833186/why-does-this-haskell-code-work-successfully-with-infinite-lists

Comment: `foldl` and `foldr` *both* process the list from left to right. [This](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/09/why-foldr-works-for-infinite-lists-and-foldl-doesnt/) may help you understand folds more profoundly.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The key here is laziness. If the function you're using for folding the list is strict, then neither a left fold nor a right fold will terminate, given an infinite list.

```
Prelude> foldr (+) 0 [1..]
^CInterrupted.
```

However, if you try folding a less strict function, you can get a terminating result.

```
Prelude> foldr (\x y -> x) 0 [1..]
1
```

You can even get a result that is an infinite data structure, so while it does in a sense not terminate, it's still able to produce a result that can be consumed lazily.

```
Prelude> take 10 $ foldr (:) [] [1..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

However, this will not work with `foldl`, as you will never be able to evaluate the outermost function call, lazy or not.

```
Prelude> foldl (flip (:)) [] [1..]
^CInterrupted.
Prelude> foldl (\x y -> y) 0 [1..]
^CInterrupted.
```

Note that the key difference between a left and a right fold is not the order in which the list is traversed, which is always from left to right, but rather how the resulting function applications are nested.

- With `foldr`, they are nested on "the inside"

  ```
  foldr f y (x:xs) = f x (foldr f y xs)
  ```

  Here, the first iteration will result in the outermost application of `f`. Thus, `f` has the opportunity to be lazy so that the second argument is either not always evaluated, or it can produce some part of a data structure without forcing its second argument.
- With `foldl`, they are nested on "the outside"

  ```
  foldl f y (x:xs) = foldl f (f y x) xs
  ```

  Here, we can't evaluate anything until we have reached the outermost application of `f`, which we will never reach in the case of an infinite list, regardless of whether `f` is strict or not.

Comment: This is interesting: foldr (\x y -> x) 0 [1..]. Is it really an example of lazy evaluation? Or is it just the compiler being smart? Like, I don't see how it ever could be evaluated in the traditional sense, but it's quite obvious what the final value will be. So is GHC actually lazily evaluating (and if so, how the ***? :P) or is it just smart enough to recognise that the answer will always be 1?

Comment: @ThelronKnuckle It's lazy evaluation.  Or rather it's the non-strict semantics of Haskell.  The compiler is not allowed to change that no matter how smart it is.

Comment: @ThelronKnuckle It is lazy evaluation unless the compiler performs supercompilation.

Comment: Alright fine, lazy evaluation it may be, but _at some point_ it has to be evaluated, so what the heck is actually happening? Does it stick 'infinity' in the accumulator, then fold right and wack 'infinity - 1' in the accumulator, then 'infinity - 2' and so on all the way down to 1? Or is GHC just smart enough to see that the result will be 1, and just put that in instead?

Comment: @hammar, brilliant. It's all clear now. I was still thinking imperatively and there's the paradigm shift :p Cheers

Comment: @ThelronKnuckle: No, it does not have to be evaluated. Lazy evaluation means you only evaluate what you use, so if you only use the first 10 elements of an infinite list, only those 10 will be evaluated. Think of `let` statements and function definitions as 'recipes': they don't do anything but state how you can calculate a value when you need it. In this sense, a Haskell program doesn't really do anything by itself; the fact that it does is a consequence of evaluating `main` and executing the IO actions it returns.

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle: Here's how it evaluates: `foldr (\x y -> x) 0 [1..] ={definition of foldr} (\x y -> x) 1 (foldr (\x y -> x) 0 [2..]) ={fill in x argument} (\y -> 1) (foldr (\x y -> x) 0 [2..]) ={fill in y argument} 1`

Comment: Yeah, I get how lazy evaluation works, it just took me a while to understand how it ties in with right folding. I was thinking of folding in terms of the process instead of the function definition, and that was what was causing my confusion.

Comment: You have a mistake in your definition of foldr. Instead of 
foldr f y (x:xs) = f y (foldr f x xs)
it should be
foldr f y (x:xs) = f x (foldr f y xs)

Comment: This answer is the best explanation of an issue I found quite confusing for a long time. If I'd seen it at the time I would've Got It a lot quicker. +10 if I could

Comment: You could also include the images from [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold#List_folds_as_structural_transformations) which illustrate the difference between `foldl` and `foldr` nicely.

Comment: @hammar `foldl` should be `foldl f y (x:xs) = foldl f (f y x) xs`. =)

Answer (score 18):

The key phrase is "at some point".

> if you take an infinite list **at some point** and you fold it up from the right, you'll eventually reach the beginning of the list.

So you're right, you can't possibly start at the "last" element of an infinite list. But the author's point is this: suppose you could. Just pick a point waaay far out there (for engineers, this is "close enough" to infinity) and start folding leftwards. Eventually you end up at the start of the list. The same is not true of the left fold, if you pick a point waaaay out there (and call it "close enough" to the start of the list), and start folding rightwards, you still have an infinite way to go.

So the trick is, sometimes you don't need to go to infinity. You may not need to even go waaaay out there. But you may not know how far out you need to go beforehand, in which case infinite lists are quite handy.

The simple illustration is `foldr (:) [] [1..]`. Let's perform the fold.

Recall that `foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)`. On an infinite list, it actually doesn't matter what `z` is so I'm just keeping it as `z` instead of `[]` which clutters the illustration

```
foldr (:) z (1:[2..])         ==> (:) 1 (foldr (:) z [2..])
1 : foldr (:) z (2:[3..])     ==> 1 : (:) 2 (foldr (:) z [3..])
1 : 2 : foldr (:) z (3:[4..]) ==> 1 : 2 : (:) 3 (foldr (:) z [4..])
1 : 2 : 3 : ( lazily evaluated thunk - foldr (:) z [4..] )
```

See how `foldr`, despite theoretically being a fold from the *right*, in this case actually cranks out individual elements of the resultant list starting at the *left*? So if you `take 3` from this list, you can clearly see that it will be able to produce `[1,2,3]` and need not evaluate the fold any farther.

Comment: The "pick some point and work back from the right" part really is the key here, not just an illustration--because the "some point" in question is simply the furthest point you actually use. So actually we can define "infinity" as "at least one more than we ended up needing", which I think is a definition that would satisfy both engineers *and* mathematicians.

Answer (score 12):

Remember in Haskell you can use infinite lists because of lazy evaluation.  So, `head [1..]` is just 1, and `head $ map (+1) [1..]` is 2, even though `[1..] is infinitely long.  If you dont get that, stop and play with it for a while.  If you do get that, read on...

I think part of your confusion is that the `foldl` and `foldr` always start at one side or the other, hence you dont need to give a length.

`foldr` has a very simple definition

```
 foldr _ z [] = z
 foldr f z (x:xs) = f x $ foldr f z xs
```

why might this terminate on infinite lists, well try

```
 dumbFunc :: a -> b -> String
 dumbFunc _ _ = "always returns the same string"
 testFold = foldr dumbFunc 0 [1..]
```

here we pass into `foldr` a "" (since the value doesn't matter) and the infinite list of natural numbers.  Does this terminate?   Yes.

The reason it terminates is because Haskell's evaluation is equivalent to lazy term rewriting.

So

```
 testFold = foldr dumbFunc "" [1..]
```

becomes (to allow pattern matching)

```
 testFold = foldr dumbFunc "" (1:[2..])
```

which is the same as (from our definition of fold)

```
 testFold = dumbFunc 1 $ foldr dumbFunc "" [2..]
```

now by the definition of `dumbFunc` we can conclude

```
 testFold = "always returns the same string"
```

This is more interesting when we have functions that do something, but are sometimes lazy.  For example

```
foldr (||) False
```

is used to find if a list contains any `True` elements.  We can use this to define the higher order functionn `any` which returns `True` if and only if the passed in function is true for some element of the list

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
any f = (foldr (||) False) . (map f)
```

The nice thing about lazy evaluation, is that this will stop when it encounters **the first** element `e` such that `f e == True`

On the other hand, this isn't true of `foldl`.  Why?  Well a really simple `foldl` looks like

```
foldl f z []     = z                  
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

Now, what would have happened if we tried our example above

```
testFold' = foldl dumbFunc "" [1..]
testFold' = foldl dumbFunc "" (1:[2..])
```

this now becomes:

```
testFold' = foldl dumbFunc (dumbFunc "" 1) [2..]
```

so

```
testFold' = foldl dumbFunc (dumbFunc (dumbFunc "" 1) 2) [3..]
testFold' = foldl dumbFunc (dumbFunc (dumbFunc (dumbFunc "" 1) 2) 3) [4..]
testFold' = foldl dumbFunc (dumbFunc (dumbFunc (dumbFunc (dumbFunc "" 1) 2) 3) 4) [5..]
```

and so on and so on.  We can never get anywhere, because Haskell always evaluates the outermost function first (that is lazy evaluation in a nutshell).

One cool consequence of this is that you can implement `foldl` out of `foldr` but not vice versa.  This means that in some profound way `foldr` is the most fundamental of all the higher order string functions, since it is the one we use to implement almost all the others.  You still might want to use a `foldl` sometimes, because you *can* implement `foldl` tail recursively, and get some performance gain from that.

Comment: Still reading your post, commenting as I go: Will this terminate on an infinite list of "false" values? foldr (||) False. I can see how it would terminate on an infinite list so long ast there's a True in there somewhere, but if the list is just false forever that will result in nontermination right?

Comment: Yeah, I just ran it through ghci (should've just done it in the first place :P). It didn't terminate

Comment: Glad my code was correct.  The fact that it doesn't terminate makes sense. If you give me a list one at a time, I can only tell if it has had any true values up to now, not if it will in the future.  So the fastest way to tell if a list has any true elements is to go through and stop at the first one, which is what the `foldr` code does, obviously "stop at the first one" doesn't terminate if you cant find a first one...

Answer (score 0):

There is good plain explanation on [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'). It shows step-by-step reduction with different types of fold and accumulator functions.

Answer (score -3):

Your understanding is correct. I wonder if the author is trying to talk about Haskell's lazy evaluation system (in which you can pass an infinite list to various functions not including fold, and it will only evaluate however much is needed to return the answer). but I agree with you that the author isn't doing a good job describing anything in that paragraph, and what it says is wrong.

Comment: Why *not including fold*? Try this: `foldr (:) [] [1..]`

Comment: No. The paragraph might be *unclear*, but nothing it says is *wrong*. It is talking about lazy evaluation, and the justification given is exactly why `foldr` can in fact work on infinite lists.

Comment: Stupid thing is that if I had just kept reading the book I would have run into the explanation I wanted only a few pages later :p