# Why right folding can process infinite list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, infinite, fold

For an infinite list, there's no "last" element of it. So how could `foldr` work with it?

I've this code snippet from the Haskell book:

```
(&&)::Bool->Bool->Bool
True && x = x
False && _ = False

and' :: [Bool]->Bool
and' xs=foldr (Main.&&) True xs
```

Then in Prelude load this hs file and run:

```
*Main> and' (repeat False)
False
```

It works as expected, but I don't understand:

1. The definition of the `(&&)` receives boolean on the left of it,
      but we apply `True && x = x` while the variable `x` is in its right side. 
      Isn't it strange?
2. Why `foldr` stops when `(&&)` returns `False`?
      In my understanding `foldr` will loop through the list from tail till head.
      Is there any internal "break" mechanism?
3. `foldr` starts from the last element of a list, but infinite list has no end. 
      How does `foldr` begin to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left and Right Folding over an Infinite list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396978/left-and-right-folding-over-an-infinite-list)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833186/why-does-this-haskell-code-work-successfully-with-infinite-lists?rq=1. Either way, ___one question per post___. Your first one is different from your second and third. The second and third are duplicates of others. Also, `foldr` does not start from the right; it associates to the right: `f a (f b (f c( ... ))))`. Clean up your question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your first question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's repeat your definitions and add a couple more:

```
(&&)::Bool->Bool->Bool
True && x = x
False && _ = False

and :: [Bool]->Bool
and xs = foldr (&&) True xs

repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat a = a : repeat a

foldr :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (a:as) = f a (foldr f z as)
```

Now, we can prove this by evaluating it manually, taking care to do it "lazily" (outermost applications first, and evaluating only enough to resolve the outermost data constructors):

```
and (repeat False)
  = foldr (&&) True (repeat False)           -- definition of `and`
  = foldr (&&) True (False : repeat False)   -- definition of `repeat`
  = False && foldr (&&) True (repeat False)  -- `foldr`, second equation
  = False                                    -- `&&`, second equation
```

The key is that the second equation of the definition of `&&` discards its second argument:

```
False && _ = False
```

This means, in runtime terms, that we never force `foldr`'s recursive call at a step where we encounter `False`.

Another way to look at it is to contemplate `foldr`'s second equation, and what it means when we have lazy evaluation:

```
foldr f z (a:as) = f a (foldr f z as)
```

Since the recursive call to `foldr` happens as an argument to `f`, this means that, at runtime, the function `f` decides whether the value of its second argument is necessary or not, and so chooses at each step of the fold whether to recurse down the list or not.  And this "decision" process proceeds from left to right.

---

> In my understanding foldr will loop through the list from tail till head. Is there any internal "break" mechanism?

Strictly speaking, in a pure functional language there is no intrinsic notion of evaluation order.  Expressions may be evaluated in any order that's consistent with their data dependencies.

What you've said here is a common misunderstanding that people who've learned `foldr` from impure, eager languages carry over to Haskell.  In an eager language that's a useful rule of thumb, but in Haskell, with purity lazy evaluation, that rule will only confuse you.  Often the *opposite* rule of thumb is useful when programming Haskell: `foldr` will visit the list elements from left to right, and at each step its `f` argument function gets to decide whether the rest of the list is necessary.

The extreme example of this is to implement a function to get the head of a list using `foldr`:

```
-- | Return `Just` the first element of the list, or `Nothing` if the
-- list is empty.
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead = foldr (\a _ -> Just a) Nothing
```

So for example:

```
safeHead [1..]
  = foldr (\a _ -> Just a) Nothing [1..]
  = foldr (\a _ -> Just a) Nothing (1:[2..])
  = (\a _ -> Just a) 1 (foldr (\a _ -> Just a) Nothing [2..])
  = Just 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to familiarize with the syntax a bit.
In Haskell, a function definition goes like this:

```
 this   =   that
```

and, basically, it means: When you see *this* it means *that*. In fact

```
True && x
```

is the same as `x`, and

```
False && x
```

is `False`, that is why we can write the definitions as in your example.

For your second question: it is not the case that `foldr` "stops". It is the `&&` operator who does not evaluate its right operand, when the left one is `False`.

For your 3rd question: no, `foldr` does not start from the last element of a list. Please have a look at the definition of foldr:

```
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = x `f`  foldr f z xs
```

Now suppose

```
foldr (&&) True (False:xs)
```

it evaluates to

```
False && foldr (&&) True xs
```

And since

```
False && _
```

is `False`, the result is `False`

Comment: Shouldn't "foldr f z [] = z" be "foldr f z [] = f z"? I suppose f should be applied?

Comment: And what does `f` mean?

Comment: Infix application of **f** (you should really go at least through LYAH, as it is near impossible to discuss things when most basic syntax is not known). This also means that f is a function with two arguments, so no, it would not make sense to apply it to z in the first equation.